# Service Fabric's Property Management API and Traefik Extension

Tags: azure-service-fabric, traefik, service-fabric-stateless

**Environment:**

An application deployed to Service Fabric using service manifest in which I've configured Traefik's extension labels:

```
<ServiceTypes>
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="MySrvType" UseImplicitHost="true">
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Name="Traefik">
          <Labels xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/03/fabact-no-schema">
            <Label Key="traefik.enable">true</Label>
          </Labels>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </StatelessServiceType>
  </ServiceTypes>
```

**Problem:**

I can use the Property Management API to modify the value of the `traefik.enable` label (according to https://github.com/jjcollinge/traefik-on-service-fabric#dynamically-updating-service-labels):

```
curl -X PUT --cert cert.pem --key pkey.pem --http1.1 -kv -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"PropertyName": "traefik.enable","Value": {"Kind": "String","Data": "false"}}' 'https://****.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Names/MyApp/MyService/$/GetProperty?api-version=6.0'
```

This changes the value and I can see that Traefik no longer list that service in its dashboard.

However, before I use the PUT API to change the value, I'd like to use the GET API to read the value of that label:

```
curl --cert cert.pem --key pkey.pem --http1.1 -kv -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'https://****.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Names/MyApp/MyService/$/GetProperty?api-version=6.0&PropertyName=traefik.enable'
```

*This returns 404*:

```
{"Error":{"Code":"FABRIC_E_PROPERTY_DOES_NOT_EXIST","Message":"Property does not exist."}}
```

If I'd used the PUT API to update the value first, the GET API finds the property and returns its latest value. This seems like a bug to me since the PUT API finds the property and updating it disables the service in Traefik.